# Keyboard shortcut completion help in emacs?

Tags: emacs

I was wondering if there is anything in emacs which will help me remember keyboard shortcuts?

For example, if I press C-x and then press some key (say TAB), emacs should all possible combinations of C-X and other keys to give an emacs command (and also show what the command does)?

Answer (score 39, accepted):

There is a simpler way to do this than `C-h m`. You can see all the combinations you need by pressing `C-h`. Let me explain with an example.  Say you want to run the command `org-narrow-to-subtree`, which in my case is bound to `C-x n s` I remember that I have to type `C-x n` but don't remember the next part. I can type `C-x n C-h` and emacs will show me the following:

```
Global Bindings Starting With C-x n:
key             binding
---             -------

C-x n d     narrow-to-defun
C-x n n     narrow-to-region
C-x n p     narrow-to-page
C-x n r     narrow-to-region
C-x n s     org-narrow-to-subtree
C-x n w     widen

[back]
```

So in your case, to see all possibilities after `C-x`, just type `C-x C-h`

Answer (score 5):

You can use `C-h m` to list and describe all active keybindings in current buffer (depending on your active major and minor modes).

Answer (score 4):

Not a complete answer but partial:

- The Emacs user manual has a key index which lists all the key sequences (Emacs' preferred term for what you call keyboard shortcuts).
- C-x C-h opens a buffer listing key sequences beginning C-x.
- C-h k followed by a key sequence describes the key sequence.
- C-h K followed by a key sequence takes you to the right page of the user manual.

Answer (score 3):

I think one-key is what's your looking for [One key](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/OneKey)

Answer (score 1):

In [***Icicles***](http://www.emacswiki.org/cgi-bin/wiki/Icicles) you have [***key completion***](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/Icicles_-_Key_Completion),
which is just about what you described.

You know the help that is offered when you hit a prefix key and then <kbd>C-h</kbd> -- e.g. <kbd>C-x C-h</kbd>? Well that's just help, and it works only for certain prefixes.

What this **Icicles** feature is about is actually completing key sequences: hit <kbd>C-x</kbd>, then <kbd>S-TAB</kbd> to complete, and every possible completion of prefix key <kbd>C-x</kbd> is displayed -- just pick one.

If the candidate you picked is itself a prefix key (e.g. you picked <kbd>r</kbd>, so so far you're up to <kbd>C-x r</kbd>, which is still incomplete), then you pick another piece of the sequence, and so on, until the key sequence is complete (and its command is invoked).

See also:

- [You can complete key sequences too.](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/Icicles_-_Nutshell_View#KeyCompletion)
- [Which keys can I use now, and what do they do?](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/EmacsNewbieWithIcicles#PossibleKeyBindings)